# Laravel whereNotExists not working properly

Tags: database, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

As far as I understand whereNotExists, it should exclude all the queries within the closure passed.
However, I am getting unexpected results.

What I am trying to do is return all of the students that apply to the conditions of the closure; students that are not set as absent or absent by parent. What I am getting is an empty students array [].

What am I doing wrong?

```
    $students = DB::table('rounds')
                ->where('rounds.bus_id', '=', $bus_id)
                ->join('rounds_students', 'rounds_students.round_id', 'rounds.id')
                ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                     $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                        ->from('student_history')
                        ->where('student_history.student_id', '=', 'rounds_students.student_id')
                        ->where('student_history.activity_type', '=', 'absent')
                        ->orWhere('student_history.activity_type', '=', 'absent-by-parent');
                    })
                ->join('students', 'students.id', 'rounds_students.student_id')
                ->select('students.name')
                ->get();
            return $students;
```

Comment: Typically the `NOT EXISTS` subquery uses some element of the outer query. Here you are not doing that at all.

Comment: @apokryfos I already did that but forgot to mention it in the question. Updated the question with it. I still got an empty $students array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to use a raw expression with `whereRaw()` or `where(DB::raw('...'))` to define a correlation condition in the `NOT EXISTS` clause. Otherwise `'rounds_students.student_id'` would be passed as a string value, which is not what you want.
2. Beware of `AND`s and `OR`s in your `WHERE` conditions! Yours was incorrect. Changed it to `whereIn` to make it more succinct.

Also you don't really need to use `select(DB::RAW(1))` in `EXISTS` clauses. Database optimizers know that they don't need to return any resultset to the outer query. This may help to keep your code less bloated.

Try

```php
$students = DB::table('rounds')
    ->select('students.name')
    ->join('rounds_students', 'rounds_students.round_id', 'rounds.id')
    ->join('students', 'students.id', 'rounds_students.student_id')
    ->where('rounds.bus_id', $bus_id)
    ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
        $query->from('student_history')
            ->whereRaw('student_history.student_id = rounds_students.student_id')
            ->whereIn('student_history.activity_type', ['absent', 'absent-by-parent']);
    })
    ->get();
```